# Web application getting destroyed after few simultaneous HTTP request

Tags: web-services, spring, tomcat, c3p0

After making around 10-15 simultaneous request to the spring based web-services running on Tomcat closes the web application. 
Please suggest the solution based on the following error log :

```
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 48 AM **org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port.Stopping the Server instance.**
Feb 13,
2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 13,
2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 13,
2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 13,
2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing WebApplicationContext
for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date[Wed Feb 13 10: 57: 18 IST 2013];
parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Feb 13,
2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@33d98c: defining beans[org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer #0,dataSources,jdbcTemplate,namedParameterJdbcTemplate,GDOController,mastersController,syncController,ordersController,reportController,accountsController,loginController,PPLPReceiptController,inventoryController,receiptController,quoteController,geoTagCustomerController,sapController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping# 0, org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean #0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter# 0, org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor #0,txManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource# 0, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor #0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@727256
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Feb 13 10:57:15 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@727256: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer# 0, dataSources, jdbcTemplate, namedParameterJdbcTemplate, GDOController, mastersController, syncController, ordersController, reportController, accountsController, loginController, PPLPReceiptController, inventoryController, receiptController, quoteController, geoTagCustomerController, sapController, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping #0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean# 0, org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter #0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor# 0, txManager, org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator, org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource #0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor# 0, org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor, org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl #0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository# 0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy #0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager# 0, org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased #0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor# 0, org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator #0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider# 0, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache #0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint# 0, org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor #0,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager# 0, org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider #0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher# 0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager];
root of factory hierarchy
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing WebApplicationContext
for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date[Wed Feb 13 10: 57: 14 IST 2013];
parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Feb 13,
2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@ed5ed5: defining beans[org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer #0,dataSources,jdbcTemplate,namedParameterJdbcTemplate,GDOController,mastersController,syncController,ordersController,reportController,accountsController,loginController,PPLPReceiptController,inventoryController,receiptController,quoteController,geoTagCustomerController,sapController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping# 0, org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean #0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter# 0, org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor #0,txManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource# 0, org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor #0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@16e47a1
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Feb 13 10:57:11 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@16e47a1: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer# 0, dataSources, jdbcTemplate, namedParameterJdbcTemplate, GDOController, mastersController, syncController, ordersController, reportController, accountsController, loginController, PPLPReceiptController, inventoryController, receiptController, quoteController, geoTagCustomerController, sapController, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping #0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean# 0, org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter #0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor# 0, txManager, org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator, org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource #0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor# 0, org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor, org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl #0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository# 0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy #0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager# 0, org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased #0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor# 0, org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator #0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider# 0, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache #0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint# 0, org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor #0,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager# 0, org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider #0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher# 0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager];
root of factory hierarchy
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 48 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application[/DrishtiProduction] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'mvc-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Feb 13 10:54:28 IST 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@181cb9b: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSources,jdbcTemplate,namedParameterJdbcTemplate,GDOController,mastersController,syncController,ordersController,reportController,accountsController,loginController,PPLPReceiptController,inventoryController,receiptController,quoteController,geoTagCustomerController,sapController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,txManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3cd16e
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
INFO: Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Feb 13 10:54:24 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3cd16e: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,dataSources,jdbcTemplate,namedParameterJdbcTemplate,GDOController,mastersController,syncController,ordersController,reportController,accountsController,loginController,PPLPReceiptController,inventoryController,receiptController,quoteController,geoTagCustomerController,sapController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,txManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.config.http.UserDetailsServiceInjectionBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:48 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 13, 2013 10:58:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr / java / packages / lib / i386: /lib:/usr / lib
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 52 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 860 ms
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat / 7.0.27
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive / usr / share / apache - tomcat - 7.0.27 / webapps / DrishtiProduction.war
Feb 13, 2013 10: 58: 53 AM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see from the above log, something is sending a termination signal to tomcat.
Check for the services running in background which may be affecting tomcat. TOMCAT_HOME/bin has catalina.sh/catalina.bat. Running these would cause tomcat to shutdown.

```
[INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port.Stopping the Server instance.**]
```

This above statement justifies it.